# Setting Temp Variable in a PHP script that can be re-accessed

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I am wanting to set a variable on my locally on my server that can quickly be checked, preferably stored in RAM that I can pull back up and change every time a particular PHP script is accessed. I would write the variable to a file and then pull it back up, but I rather not do it that way, because I want it to be very low overhead on the server to perform the task.

What are my options to do this?

As a for instance.
Visitor 1 hits my page, site.com/page.php variable is written.
Visitor 2 hits my page (site.com/page.php), I am able to pull back that variable that was written when visitor 1 hit the same page.

I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: You can use Redis

Comment: Use an in-memory database like Redis, APCu, memcached or similar

Comment: Or just the file system or a database, unless you can prove that those aren't performant enough for your use case.

Comment: If you decide to store the updated value to a file, be sure to use the `flock` function to ensure serial access to the file.